# How do you get composer to install a non-composer package?

Tags: php, composer-php, packagist

I am trying to get composer to download the following library from this project, however, it does not have a `composer.json` file in it so I'm not sure if this is possible.

```
{
    "require" : {
        "fguillot/picoFeed" : "*"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/fguillot/picoFeed"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Error:**

> [Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException]
>   No valid composer.json was found in any branch or tag of
>   https://github.com/fguillot/picoFeed, could not load a package
>   from it.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

To include a non composer repository you need to set up a [package repository](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2). Which would give you something like:

```js
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "fguillot/picoFeed",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/fguillot/picoFeed",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "origin/master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "fguillot/picoFeed": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the installer path for such a "package"?

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the answer from @George, regarding the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847994/how-do-you-get-composer-to-install-a-non-composer-package/34397085#comment46285882_16873912) from @DavidOliver, here's how you *should* be able to change the package install target:

```
"repositories" : [
    {
        "type"    : "package",
        "package" : {
            "name"    : "vend0r/p4ckage",
            "version" : "dev-master",
            "type"    : "foo-library",
            "dist"    : {
                "url"  : "https://github.com/vend0r/p4ckage.git",
                "type" : "vend0r/p4ckage"
            },
            "source"  : {
                "url"       : "https://github.com/vend0r/p4ckage.git",
                "type"      : "git",
                "reference" : "origin/master"
            }
        }
    }
]
...
"extra" : {
    "installer-paths" : {
        "libraries/footype" : [
            "type:foo-library"
        ],
    }
}
...
"require" : {
    "vend0r/p4ckage" : "dev-master"
}
```

Comment: I stumbled upon this looking how to install a non-composer repository to a custom path; it turns out that it cannot be done by only requiring `composer/installers`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20442240/1065925 .
There's also a solution with `oomphinc/composer-installers-extender` on the same page.