# composer is ignoring installer-paths configuration

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php

I'm try using CakePHP for the first time with composer, but I have some problems.

I have this `composer.json`:

```
{
  "name": "example.com.br",
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "pear",
      "url": "http://pear.cakephp.org"
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "vendor-dir": "Vendor/"
  },
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4",
    "pear-cakephp/cakephp": ">=2.4.3",
    "cakephp/debug_kit": "2.2.*",
    "smottt/wideimage": "dev-master"
  },
  "extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
      "app/Plugin/DebugKit": ["cakephp/debug_kit"],
      "app/Vendor/Wideimage": ["smottt/wideimage"]
    }
  }  
}
```

When I run `composer install (or update) --prefer-dist`, everything works except `smottt/wideimage`.

This package is being installed in the `/Vendor` folder instead `/app/Vendor`, so, **installer-paths** was ignored.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md).

> You cannot use this to change the path of any package. This is only
>   applicable to packages that require composer/installers and use a
>   custom type that it handles.

From one of the [packages](https://github.com/smottt/WideImage/blob/master/composer.json) you're installing:

```
{
    "name": "smottt/wideimage",
    "description": "An open-source PHP library for image manipulation. (With namespaces, PHP 5.3+)",
    "homepage": "http://wideimage.sourceforge.net",
    "type": "library",
    "license": ["GPL-2.0","LGPL-2.1"],
    "version": "11.02.19",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0" : {
          "WideImage" : "lib/"
        }
    }
}
```

So basically the package you're trying to install doesn't support custom install paths.

Answer (score 19):

Of course, what [Danack has said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20442240/5803236) is true: the *composer-installers* plugin only supports a select list of package types.

In response to that, I have written [an extension](https://github.com/oomphinc/composer-installers-extender) for the *composer-installers* plugin which allows any arbitrary package type to be handled by the `"installer-paths"` directive.

Simply require [`oomphinc/composer-installers-extender`](https://packagist.org/packages/oomphinc/composer-installers-extender) in your composer.json and add support for any additional arbitrary package types:

```
"extra": {
  "installer-types": ["library"],
  "installer-paths": {
    "special/package/": ["my/package"],
    "path/to/libraries/{$name}/": ["type:library"]
  }
}
```

For packages that don't specify a type, use the default type `library`.

Comment: Nice work, but if I put library, all package with type library are in the specified folder where I'd like the the one package to be in a specific folder.

Comment: I also have the problem that the library type moves all vendors into a specific folder and custom types are ignored.

Comment: Are you putting `type:library` in your config? I think that's expected to move all packages of that type. If you only want to change a specific package, then use the package name instead. That's shown in the `"special/package/": ["my/package"]` line in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use option "script" of composer (work only with linux) :

```
"scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php -r \"system('mv '.getcwd().'/Vendor/smottt/wideimage '.getcwd().'/Vendor/Wideimage');\""
        ]
    }
```

Comment: This isn't elegant in any way but was the only way to get it installing into the correct dir for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add your custom types to the `installer-types`:

```json
{
  "installer-types": ["library", "myttype-1", "mytype-2"]
}
```

https://packagist.org/packages/oomphinc/composer-installers-extender