# Autoload Vendor with CakePHP v3.x and Composer

Tags: php, cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to load [this](https://github.com/thoughtco/Freeagent-PHP) into my CakePHP 3.x app. I'm totally clueless as to how I might do this with composer. I've included other files with composer already but this wrapper doesn't seem to support it.

So, how do I either:

- Do this with Composer
- Manually load the Vendor in 3.x

It's all obviously changed since 2.x :(

Any pointers please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get composer to install a non-composer package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847994/how-do-you-get-composer-to-install-a-non-composer-package)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was under my nose, [on the cake docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files).

Manually required the wrapper:

```
define('VENDOR', ROOT . DS . 'vendor' . DS);
require(VENDOR . 'thoughtco' . DS . 'freeagent' . DS . 'Freeagent.php');
```

Then modded the wrapper to use namespace:

```
namespace Freeagent;
```

Then instantiated it in my component.

```
use Freeagent\Freeagent;
...
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new Freeagent('id', 'key');
    }
```

Job done - maybe someone else might find it useful :)

Comment: Modifying 3rd party libs is usually a rather bad idea, unless you decide to maintain them yourself. The first choice should be a custom composer repository.

Comment: Even so, the lib didn't use namespace, and I couldn't use it in 3.x without that. I don't have to confidence to suggest changes on GitHub etc. - still kinda feel I'm always wrong - hah :)

Comment: It doesn't need to use namespaces in order to be useable with CakePHP 3.x (just don't forget to [**target the global namespace**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php#example-262)). If that would be a requirement, then you couldn't use any built in PHP classes anymore that live in the gobal namespace.

Comment: N00b mistake - I didn't know enough about namespace - I could only get it to work by adding that. Will try without.